# Google cloud function crashing after fs.writeFile

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, fs

I have a bit of a strange bug. I am using firebase's cloud functions for some data processing. Within the function, I need to (a) write a CSV to the tmp/ folder on the disk, (b) upload this file to google cloud storage.

I am using fs.writeFile to write to disk. This works fine--the data is correctly written to the tmp folder. BUT, the whole function crashes if it doesnt immediately resolve. So if there's a next step in function (like waiting for the upload to finish with google cloud storage), the function crashes.

I've been able to replicate the bug with the following simple version:

```
async.waterfall([
   function (callback) {
       fs.writeFile("tmp/testfile.txt", "hello world", function(err) {
           callback(null);
       });
   },
   function (callback) {
       setTimeout(function(){
           callback(null)
       }, 10000);
   }
], function(err){console.log("done!"})
```

Any thoughts on what could be going wrong will be super appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "the whole function crashes"?  If you're getting an error message in the logs, please edit your question to be more specific about what you're observing.

Comment: In the console, i get the following error: 
Execution took 1687 ms, finished with status: 'crash'

I should also mention that I am currently testing the function using firebase's functons:shell command

I have also tried to catch this bug using try catch, but that doesnt work :(

Comment: You should be using os.tmpdir() to get a directory that's writable by your function:  https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_tmpdir

Comment: Totally worked! You rock, Doug!

Answer (score 5):

For posterity, the problem was that I was setting the tmp folder as simply "tmp". Turns out, you need to find the temp folder using os.tmpdir(). Once you do that, it works fine.